# create visual studio solution and include settings of the applicatioon

Tags: c#, settings, installation-package

I am building a C# application. it has some parameters saved of a file named "settings.ini" .

Of course, I managed my application to read settings ,offer an interface for editing them and finally save them back to the ini file.

Would you please tell me how to include this setting file to the installation package (VS2008)
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an `ini` file, you should be using a `.config` file - that's the normal configuration option for .NET application with quite a lot of built in support.

You should be able to add an `app.config` file to your project from the new item screen in Visual Studio.

Take a look at [Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx) on MSDN for more detail and the [`AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) class (this page includes some examples).

Comment: Thank you. Would you please explain how to access settings and editing them C# code?

Comment: @Oumdaa - If you need to change settings during runtime, you may want to consider [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Dec/28/Building-a-better-NET-Application-Configuration-Class-revisited).